# Masked Image works in simulator but just creates white image on device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I am trying to merge two images into one for a screenshot. Here is the code:

```
- (void)savePhoto:(id)sender
   UIImage *snapShotImageGL1 = [glView snapUIImage];
   UIImage *maskedImage = [self maskImage:_image withMask:snapShotImageGL1];
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(maskedImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

and then:

```
#pragma mark - Image Processing

- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
   UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   return newImage;
}

- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

CGImageRef mask =  CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}

-(UIImage*)invertImage:(UIImage*)image{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeCopy);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeDifference);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),[UIColor  
    whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width,   
    image.size.height));
    UIImage *returnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return returnImage;
}
```

This is working great in the simulator but it just creates a white blank photo when running on my device. Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Check your image names in Bundle. Because Simulator does not care about whether file is case sensitive or not, but devices do.

If your image name is `"ConverImage.png"`, it'll work fine in simulator, but not in Device. Try changing that file name into `"convertimage.png"`.